# Transforming the camera using a Matrix4f

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, coordinate-transformation

I have a 3D scene with one triangle and a camera I want to move around. I stored the camera transformation as a matrix (specificially, a Matrix4f object loaded with the identity).

Here are two examples of methods that would modify that matrix:

This one rotates it a negative amount on the y axis:

```
public void turnRight() {
    getCameraMatrix().rotate(-ROTATION_INTERVAL, new Vector3f(0, 1, 0));
}
```

This one translates right:

```
public void right() {
    getCameraMatrix().translate(new Vector3f(TRANSLATION_INTERVAL, 0, 0));
}
```

I set the projection matrix to orthographic (having previously called glViewport()):

```
public void performProjection() {
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, Display.getWidth(), 0, Display.getHeight(), 0, 1000);
}
```

And change the camera position before drawing the scene every time the camera moves:

```
public void performLook() {
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glLoadMatrix(
            getAsFloatBuffer() //Gets the FloatBuffer from the matrix.
    );
}
```

However, the effect of this transformation is that the triangle is translated and rotated, not the camera. As an example of how this should happen, if the `right()` is called, the camera should move right perpendicular to its current orientation, not down some axis.

Any tips on how to do this? (*Our assignment forbids modern openGL for some reason*.)

**EDIT**

In case it's useful, the coordinates for the triangle are: `(1, 1, 1), (1, 50, 1), (50, 50, 1)`

The viewport call is `glViewport(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());`

And finally, the Display dimensions are 640x480

If there's anything about my question that needs clarification, please let me know. Thanks.

**EDIT**

The camera matrix is the model view matrix in my code. I built it by creating a new Matrix4f object and loading the identity. All subsequent transforms were added to the matrix, whose data is then moved to the model view matrix when performLook() is called. I'm only drawing a single primitive right now, so I haven't yet dealt with object to world transforms.

The render steps are:
1. performProjection()
2. performLook()
3. Clear the screen
4. Draw the primitive
5. Swap the buffers.

Comment: Post how did you build your `modelViewProjection` matrix. And how did you build that `CameraMatrix`?

Comment: Paulo, I added an edit answering your question.

Comment: how did you build the camera? it is an empty `Matrix4f` or you put something inside this matrix?

Comment: I load the identity right off the bat in the camera's constructor. Matrix4f.setIdentity()

Comment: The problem is it. Camera matrix is more complex.

Comment: Go to this `Matrix.setLookAt()` implementation: [link](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/opengl/java/android/opengl/Matrix.java) , search `setLookAt()` method. Your view matrix should be build using it. I recommend you copy and paste that method, and use it to create your view matrix.

Comment: After you had positioned your camera, you should use its inverse matrix to perform rendering calculation. Just as reminder, matrix multiplication order matter a lot

Comment: Inverse at the calculation, meaning when I load the matrix into the model view?

Comment: Yeah, get your Matrix4f and invert it before loading into opengl modelview matrix

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that as soon as I get back to the lab.